# can't connect to dynamic IP home server

Tags: port-forwarding, home-server, dynamic-ip

I have a dynamic IP that enters my home through a router, to which I'm connected via wireless. I've  created an account on dyndns.chom (badescuga.dyndns.org).

I've configured my router to use my DynDNS account successfully. I then went to the  "forwarding" tab in my router menu to add a new virtual server for port 80 using the internal IP address of 192.168.1.04 (my computer's IP address)

[image]

Although I have my Apache server up and running (`http://localhost` works), I can't connect using my domain badescuga.dyndns.org.

Comment: Did you check your current dynamic IP? It must have changed (due to restart of router or expired TTL).

Answer (score 1):

Going to the external address while behind the router doesn't always work; the router detects that the connection is local and ignores the forwarding rules, connecting the client to the router instead. Use a host or proxy outside the local network instead.